# Defining a static global array to avoid defining it in a function

Tags: c++, optimization, static-variables

I've just started working with a chunk of code that the authors claim is "highly optimized". At some point they do this:

```
namespace somename 
{ 
  static float array[N]; 
} 

float Someclass::some_function(std::vector<float>& input) 
{
  // use somename::array in some way 
  return result; 
}
```

The authors haven't included `somename::array` in the class because of issues with persistence code (which we have little control over). The class does O(N^2) operations on the array when `some_function` is called. So If I move `array` inside the function call,

```
float Someclass::some_function(std::vector<float>& input) 
{
  float array[N];
  // use somename::array in some way 
  return result; 
}
```

is it reasonable to expect a decrease in performance? In other words, is it obvious that, across many different systems and compilers, the author's optimization (using a global array rather than one inside the function) will help performance?

Comment: Why would you think this was an optimization?

Comment: did you mean 'serialization' instead of 'sterilization'?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well, I'm not sure if it is, the authors seem to think so. I'd assume because it doesn't require the function to rebuild the array every time it's called. On the other hand, most modern compilers may be smart enough to optimize around that.

Comment: It is a static declaration. It will not be rebuilt every time its called, so essentially, there doesn't seem to be any reason to believe that this is an optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rebuild" the array. If there's some work being saved, I don't see it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sorry if this wasn't clear before, I've listed both possibilities, I'm asking if one is _obviously_ faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since numbers matter:

./trial2.out  59.08s user 0.01s system 88% cpu 1:07.01 total

./trial.out  59.40s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 59.556 total

The source code: http://pastebin.com/YA2WpTSU (With alternate code commented and tested)

So, no difference. Compiled with:

```
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
```

Time results while using a non-static array within the function:

```
./trial.out  57.32s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 58.810 total

./trial.out  57.77s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 59.259 total
```

So again, no difference. Since when you use a array it is part of your function stack and not heap, there is no overhead with reserving memory every time the function is called. It would be an entirely different scenario in case you used a dynamic allocation (in which case, I do suspect that there would have been a huge difference in performance).

Comment: very nice. But I'm trying to get around using a static array, (which you have used in both functions) so the real comparison is slightly different.

Comment: how did you get the time output here?

Comment: I got the time output using the UNIX `time` command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/time

Comment: thanks, I just tried myself (without declaring the array static in trial2) and got identical results for both trials.

Comment: What optimization did you use? I just realized that this may not mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't notice the difference, but there is one! With the `static` keyword, the array exists in the DATA segment of the program and it remains the whole runtime. Without the `static` keyword, the array resides in the stack and is initialized every time you call the function. The stack version nevertheless can be the better choice because of better locality and therefore less cache misses. You have to measure which version is better in your case. In my case (one array with 69 64-Bit numbers and a second two dimensional array of 48 * 12 characters) the static version was significantly faster.

Comment: woah... I failed to follow the number one rule of benchmarking: turn on _all_ optimization. With the code from [Rohan's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465028/915501) with some small modification, I got nearly identical results for both. **But that was with -O0**. With -O3, the static version is 2 orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that "array" is allocated globally (if declared static) and it would be "allocated" on the stack if declared in the function body. What really matters here is the size of your array (N).
If it's a big array, you can leave it static because you may not be able to declare it on the stack.
A third option would be to allocate it dynamically (heap, with new keyword). However, all these suppositions won't really affect the performance of the function itself, as once, allocated, there's no overhead for any of these methods.

Comment: so if the array is allocated _inside_ the function, it likely won't effect the performance?

Comment: Since it is a static array, it isn't exactly allocated inside the function. So no... it won't affect the performance.